# Update VBA Code to look for Partial Filename instead of Exact Filename

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which works well when you look for the exact filename. However, I would like to reference only a partial filename in a specific cell.

I have tried countless different types of code to no avail.

```
Sub copyfiles()
    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    Dim xSFileDlg As FileDialog, xDFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xSPathStr As Variant, xDPathStr As Variant
    Dim xVal As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the file names:", "KuTools For Excel", ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xSFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xSFileDlg.Title = "Please select the original folder:"
    If xSFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xSPathStr = xSFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    Set xDFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xDFileDlg.Title = "Please select the destination folder:"
    If xDFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xDPathStr = xDFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    For Each xCell In xRg
        xVal = xCell.Value
        If TypeName(xVal) = "String" And xVal <> "" Then
            FileCopy xSPathStr & xVal, xDPathStr & xVal
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides **all** error messages but the errors still occur you just don't get notified. That means if there are errors you don't even notice them and so you can't fix them. So your code does not work properly. • [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Dir. Dir returns anything found in a folder and you can use a wildcard. Use a Variant variable so it can turn into an Array if more than one file is found with the provided string. Loop all files and done.

```
Dim listFiles As Variant
Dim fileName as String
fileName = Range("A2").Value
listFiles = Dir("E:\Folder\*" & fileName & "*")
Do While Len(listFiles) > 0
    'File Path
    MsgBox listFiles
    'Next File
    listFiles = Dir
Loop
```